# Detail about Win32_OperatingSystem SerialNumber

Tags: windows, serial-number

I'm searching for some information regarding Win32_OperatingSystem SerialNumber ([MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239(VS.85).aspx)).
Will this number be different when I reinstall Windows with the same key on the same machine?

I intend to use it to identify an installation (Windows + PC combination).

Comment: What happens when you try this in a virtual machine?

Comment: I didn't yet have the time to test this. I thought maybe somebody knows a good documentation about this number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not so sure about the stability of Win32_OperatingSystem.SerialNumber... but I wouldn't recommend using it as your unique identifier.

To get the serial number that's burned into the computer's hardware--i.e. that never changes*--the method that I found after some research is this:

1. Fetch **[Win32_BIOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394077%28VS.85%29.aspx).SerialNumber** -- this should work for >90% of PCs/servers, including all the major manufacturers (HP, Dell, etc.).
2. If that didn't work, then try **[Win32_BaseBoard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394072%28VS.85%29.aspx).SerialNumber**.
3. Failing that, your last resort is **[Win32_ComputerSystemProduct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394105%28VS.85%29.aspx).IdentifyingNumber**.

**Note: technically, the serial number would change if the motherboard was replaced with a new one--thus the (new) burned-in S/N wouldn't match the labels on the case... but this is a rare/unusual exception.*

Comment: Win32_BIOS.SerialNumber and Win32_BaseBoard.SerialNumber will not work in enterprise , laptops ordered in bulk will mostly have same bios serial number.

Comment: I can confirm for sure Win32_OperatingSystem.SerialNumber is changing on Windows 10 anniversary update, will it change for future major updates, I don't know but it is worth relying on 'it will change'.   See also  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e71f24c1-6b7b-4a58-9ead-9e7ab1d61616/regular-win10-updates-change-serialnumber?forum=win10itprogeneral